# How to not use aspect in spring to write the request param and response param to the console

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I found the class InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest will get the request param from request and invoke the controller class to get the return value.
What should I modify the method to write the params to the console?
I want to extends ServletInvocableHandlerMethod and override the method invokeForRequest but I can't call getMethodArgumentValues because it is private.should I copy the class of ServletInvocableHandlerMethod and InvocableHandlerMethod to modify the private method? Or is there have another way to log the request and response params without aspect?

Answer (score 0):

Just create interceptor

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

public class LoggingInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        // log here
        return true; // let go further
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        // log here
    }
}
```

and register it

```
// example for Spring MVC annotation-based configuration
public class YourWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor());
    }
    ...
}
```